# Does Watson Tone Analyzer have a limit on the input text size?

Tags: ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I am using the POST API for Watson Tone Analyzer. The documentation says, it can accept upto 128kb data, i.e. 1000 sentences at a time. But, when I give about 2500 words(17kb) only half of the sentences are returned in the analysis results. Could anyone explain this behavior? Does it have pagination or something??

Comment: I have the same issue understanding API call with 128kb payload. Were you able to resolve the issue? How did you calculate the 1000 sentences = 128kb?